# What should my url be for JAX-RS API

Tags: java, rest, localhost, jax-rs

Pardon for the amateur question, however, I am struggling with testing a java Rest Api Locally.

```
@Path("/Product")  //URL to call
public class ProductSearch {

   @Path("/item")
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public List<ProductObject> getProjects(Credentials login) throws ConnectionException{
```

Assuming credentials has username, password, url, itemname, What should the localhost url look like? I get a 404 when I go to `http://localhost:8080/productsearchapi/Product/item`

I am able to deploy to heroku and test by sending json string but I need to be able to test and debug locally.

Comment: You are creating POST request and trying to access URL directly. Are you sure about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test your POST call to the API without deploying to heroku.

Your request in postman would look similar to the following, and under the body tab you would have to create the valid JSON that your path is consuming.

[Postman Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPgCh.jpg)

After hitting send with providing a valid JSON you should get the response json returned to you